# What does gateway mean in linux route table?

Tags: linux, router, gateway, routing

Does it mean the next hop of the route? Can the gateway be the next next hop, if there is an internal router in the private network?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the gateway means the next hop of the route.  A gateway should be on the same network as the IP subnet in which it is defined, ie the gateway should be one an address which is routable by the machine.